# How do I configure puppet parameterized classes from command line (hammer-cli)?

Tags: puppet, theforeman

I want to use [hammer](https://github.com/theforeman/hammer-cli-foreman) CLI to modify the parameters of a puppet class. I tried this, but it defines a "Global" paramteter, not a class parameter.

```
hammer  host update --id 10 --parameters foo=0,bar="blah"
```

What is the command line to set a class parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a smart class parameter. Unfortunately, I think you need to wait for [this pull request to get merged](https://github.com/theforeman/hammer-cli-foreman/pull/153) in before you will be able to do this through the CLI.